# Expatriates.SE turns 5 years old today

Tags: discussion

This is just a small notification that the public beta of Expatriates.SE started in [18 March 2014 at 7pm](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates), exactly 5 years ago.

I would like to use this opportunity to thank everyone who joined this community in the past few years and helped in growing it. While we are still a small site compared to some of the large StackExchange sites I do believe it's important that we are here and help our userbase get their questions answered in the next 5 years as well.